# How can i receive a data from response using GraphQL and .NET

Tags: c#, graphql, response, hotchocolate

I need to get a text from response field (Banana Cake Pop) but don't get how to do it with GraphQL nuget. I've found code similar to

```
            var graphQLClient = new GraphQLHttpClient("url", new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer());

        graphQLClient.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer token");
        graphQLClient.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");

        var heroRequest = new GraphQLRequest
        {
            Query = @"
            {query(
            $propIdArray: [Uuid!], $objectIdArray: [Uuid!], $ts: String){
                propertyViews(
                propIdArray: $propIdArray, objectIdArray: $objectIdArray, ts: $ts
                ) {
                id,
                value,
                valueTypeId
                }
            }}"
        };

        var graphQLResponse = await graphQLClient.SendQueryAsync<object>(heroRequest);
```

But it doesn't give me anything.
The Banana Cake Pop page requset and variables and response looks like this [banana cake pop screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScOB5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be insanely simple. Just had to add a Variables property in heroRequest. Now request method looks like this

```
var myRequest = new GraphQLRequest
        {
            Query = File.ReadAllText(path),
            Variables = new
            {
                ts = string.Empty,
                filterObject = new { parentId = $"{parentId}" },
                sort = new { orders = new[] { new { direction = "ASC", property = "name" } } }
            }
        };

        var graphQLResponse = _graphQLClient.SendQueryAsync<object>(myRequest);
```